# const correctness with boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I've implemented a cache class, which is able to fill/extract records in a threadsafe way (is not shown in the example).
But i have some doubts about the const correctness of this class.

Given is the following class:

```
public:

void add(const Record& record)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Record> rec(new Record(record));
    _records.push(rec);
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Record> getRecords() const
{
    return _records;
}

private:

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Record> > _records;
```

Here the getRecords() function returns the content of the cache. But every other class which gets the records is able to modify the records, isn't it?!

So I want to return the cache as a container of const records.

My new implementation looks like this:

```
public:

void add(const Record& record)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<const Record> rec(new Record(record));
    _records.push(rec);
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Record> getRecords() const
{
    return _records;
}

private:

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Record> > _records;
```

Is this the correct way to implement the needed functionality?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Above snippets are broken.

Comment: Your cache holds strong references to its elements?

Comment: yes, but this cache works rather as a queue than a cache. The requester extract n-elements from the queue (afterwards those elements will be erased from the queue).

Comment: If you want to implement "take N elements", you should probably do that instead of `getRecords`. That *won't* be a `const` method

Comment: yes, thats right...but that wasn't my question. Therefore I implemented a simple and clean example here...

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you are right, declaring the member as `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Record> > _records;` does prevent client code from modifying the pointee object stored in your class. There is another detail worth pointing out:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Record> getRecords() const
```

This method returns the vector by value. Client code will hence always operate on a copy of the vector of Record elements, which requires every element in the container to be copied - if that's not a requirement, you might consider changing your method signature such that it returns a reference:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Record>& getRecords() const
```

which is more efficient when client code operates on the reference.